# Grid System Showing Data with row then column in Asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4, grid-system

[with row then column in Razor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYhmT.png)

below is my code and it generate the data like the image left

I wanna know it's available to generate the data like right side in Razor and Bootstrap Grid Or not

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="content">
   <div class="row text-center">
      @foreach (var i in Model){
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <div id="cookie" style="height: 100px">i.Name</div>
         </div>
      }
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

and I try to write a statement to determine and think about how to generate the right one ,

this is my Code:

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="content">
    <div class="row text-center">
      @{
        for(var countQuantity = 0; countQuantity <Model.Count() ; countQuantity ++){
         if(countQuantity % 3 == 0)
         {  @: <div class="col-md-4">  }
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="cookie" style="height: 100px">Name...</div>
         </div>
          if(countQuantity % 3 == 0)
         {  @: </div>  }
        }
     </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

but I have no idea how to showing the Model's Data on the code above using foreach... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second code snippet, in order to display Model name, make the following changes:

1. Initialize an index variable
2. Display the name value using the traditional array-index access approach.

   `<div class="container">
       <div class="content">
       <div class="row text-center"> 
                 @{ int index = 0;
                   for (var countQuantity = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
                   {
                       if (countQuantity % 3 == 0)
                       {  @: <div class="col-md-4"> }
                           <div class="col-md-12">
                               <div id="cookie" style="height:100px"> @Model[index].Name
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       if (countQuantity % 3 == 0)
                       {  @:</div> }
                       }
                   }
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>`